# Help in understanding the singular system of linear forms and non escape of mass

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, homogeneous-spaces

I am having some trouble in understanding certain portions of the following paper by KKLM
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11854-017-0033-4

So in **proposition 3.1**, they proved the estimate for any decomposable vector in exterior i product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
*It is not clear to me why decomposable vector is needed or what can go wrong for non-decomposable vectors in exterior $i$ product?* In particular I want to ask is the following statement; **The maximal compact group say $SO(m+n)$ of $SL(m+n)$ acts transitively on the decomposable wedges upto homothety, is there any proof of this statement**?

And another thing is in **Lemma3.5**, they indroduced some group $N$ and $N^{0}$ where $$N= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & * & \cdots & *\\
0 & 1 & \cdots & *\\
\vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and claimed that *there is a local diffeomorphism $f:K\to N$ where $K=SO(m+n)$ such that in nbd $\mathcal{O}$ of identity in $K$, we may write $k=p(k)f(k)$ for some $p(k)\in P^{0}$ with the Jacobian of f bounded from above and below in this neighborhood. I didn't understand how this line follows.* Here $P^0$ is defined as weak stable horosprerical subgroup $$P^{0}=\begin{bmatrix} s' & 0 \\
                        s & s''\end{bmatrix}$$ where $s\in M_{n,m},s'\in M_{m,m},s''\in M_{n,n}$ and $det(s')det(s'')=1$

And lastly **in page 258 weak horosprerical subgroup $P^0$ is defined as above**, then the claim is that every element **every element of a neighborhood of the identity in $G$ can be written as $gu$ where $u$ belongs to a nbd of identity in $U$ and $g\in P^{0}$. Where $G=SL(m+n,\mathbb{R})$ and $U=\{u_s:s\in M_{m,n}\}$ and $$u_s:=\begin{bmatrix} I_m & s \\ 0 & I_n \end{bmatrix}$$ *I can't see how this follows? I am also not sure what the weak horospherical subgroup plays role in the dynamics*.

*Any insight would be very much helpful for my understanding.*

Comment: Try to formulate your question so that one does not have to read that paper in order to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: It's difficult to formulate the question in that way. This is related to finer details of the paper and about certain tricks which they are using. This is a very influential paper so ofcourse there would be people in Mathoverflow who has gone through it. That's why I asked it here.

Comment: Ok, good luck then.

Comment: I have edited the question for better understanding even without the paper. Please look into it , if you have some insight to suggest.

Comment: Try to do a further clean up of your question, it is still very unclear as written.  1. What do you mean by a decomposable wedge? Do you mean a monomial of the form $v_1\wedge v_2 \wedge ... \wedge v_N$, where the vectors $v_i$ belong to a certain inner product vector space $V$? Such a monomial (up to a nonzero multiple) depends only on the linear span of the vectors $v_i$ and then the claim follows from the fact that $O(N)$ acts transitively on the Grassmannian of $N$-dimensional  subspaces in $V$. 2. If you wrote your $K$ and $N$ correctly, then there is  no local diffeomorphism  $K\to N$.

Comment: For 2) can you please go to https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11854-017-0033-4  page no 265 lemma 3.5. You don't need to go through it, these two are the first two lines of the lemma. Also I am trying to do further clean up of question 1 and 3.

Comment: Sorry, but no, see my first comment.

Comment: Yes decomposable wedge means what you have written. And I think I have quoted $K$ and $N$ correctly as written in the paper. For the question 3) any insight?

Comment: What is your definition of a local diffeomorphism $f: X\to Y$ between smooth manifolds? There is a standard definition but there is no chance you are using it.

Comment: The authors have used local diffeomorphism term only.  Can you please elaborate why the standard definition doesn't give $k=p(k)f(k)$ in some neighborhood?

Comment: Here is the standard definition: Let $X, Y$ be smooth manifolds. A map $f: X\to Y$ is called a local diffeomorphism if it for every $x\in X$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ in $Y$ such that $f(U)=V$ and $f|_U: U\to V$ is a diffeomorphism. A pleasant exercise is to prove that there is no local diffeomorphism from a (nonempty) compact manifold to a connected noncompact manifold.

Comment: I see yes. Ok then there must be any other definition the authors are using but it is not mentioned anywhere in the paper. So I am bit confused now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, these are just basic technical tidbits. Unsure if anything here is of research level.
$SO(n)$ acts transitively on the sphere of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (there's a slight ambiguity about $0$, but I guess they say $0=0+0$ or so). Hence up to homothety, you get the same result for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (again, without $0$).

For the higher wedges, one just need to move wedge products, it is fairly standard fact that $SO(n)$ moves orthogonal frames to orthogonal frames (note it is enough to discuss orthogonal frames), as Moishe Kohan mentioned.
I think what they called "decomposable" would be called more commonly "standard/basic wedge".

For 3.5, locally, moving to the Lie algbera, you have a splitting of the Lie algbera as $\mathcal{g}^{-}\oplus \mathcal{g}^{0}\oplus \mathcal{g}^{+}$ (say for a generic Cartan element). One gets that $\exp(\mathcal{g}^{-}\oplus \mathcal{g}^{0})$ is exactly the (weak)-stable horospherical subgroup. Now it is just an eimplict function theorem argument. Jacobian is $1$ on the nose at the identity, so it is bounded on a small compact neighborhood. I suspect when they wrote ``local diffeo'' they meant in a small enough neighborhood of identity, there is a diffeo from that neighborhood to itself.

Regarding the role of horospherical subgroups, in general these subgroups played a key role in the subject of measure rigidity, going all the way from Furstenberg's work to Dani's and obviously to Ratner's (c.f. the Acta paper).
The thing is that one is interested in the unstable horospherical subgroup which get expanded and carrys the entropy. The stable horospherical subgroup is simply not very interesting dynamically as the orbits under it perfectly (exponentially) resemble the original orbit.
As the authors tried to prove a Margulis inequality, the most important thing one needs to prove for a Margulis inequality is the local expansion of the Markov operator in the f.d. reps, namely Prop 3.1.
Such an argument CANNOT hold for "weak stable" action (as you don't get any expansion, so definitely Prop. 3.1. cannot hold). You need some "hyperbolicity" in your action for a Margulis inequality to hold.

Since the writing of that paper there were several key advancements that demonstrated it is better to work with $AN$ rather than $AK$ (which they use here, as $AK$ was the first case to be considered, say in Eskin-Margulis-Mozes) as it leads to a more "direct" proof, rather than trying to bootstrap the $AK$ proof to $AN$ (which is what they try to do here, which is kind of redundant if you see the lemma in Eskin-Margulis-Mozes).
The most prominent example appears in Lindenstrauss-Mohammadi, but also the recent works of Katz and Mohammadi-Oh.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please calrify some of the things you mentioned for my better understanding. The authors proved Margulis inequality what do you mean by " local expansion of Markov operator in the f.d reps? Also you mentioned that propoosition 3.1 can't hold for weak stable action so they need some hyperbolicity. But they proved proposition 3.1 using lemma 3.5 which uses weak stable subgroup. **What do you mean by doesn't hold for weak stable action and what is the meaning of hyperbolicity in this context?** It would be very helpful if you can elaborate this.

Comment: Proposition 3.1 demonstrates local expansion of vector in f.d. reps by the Markov operator.
Lemma 3.5 uses TRANSLATE of the unstable horospherical subgroup $U$ (see (1.2)). Just using $U$ alone would not work (it is unipotent in the same Jordan block). It is absolutely crucial that one uses the $A$ element to generate expansion by its expanding action (hyperbolicity), as seen in the end of the proof of Lemma 3.5.

Comment: Sorry, but can you please elaborate a little more. What I intended to ask was what is the meaning of local expansion of a vector in finite dimensional reps by Markov operator? Reps meaning representatives I hope. Also lemma 3.5 used translate of $U$ can you please elaborate why working with just $U$ would not work? And what is the $A$ element which generate the expansion that you mentioned? Also in your answer, you mentioned that for weak stable action there is no expansion can you please mention why so? In lemma 3.5, the make the use of $P^0$ why it is necessary?

Comment: Since, I am new to this topics, if you elaborate a bit more it would be very helpful for my conceptual understanding. I didn't understand what was the intuition behind choosing these groups $N,P^0$  and $U$ in lemma 3.5. Is it anyway a standard tool?

Comment: Reps is a standard shortening of representations. In Margulis inequality, one defines a Markov operator, in their case it is the $AK$ average $Af(x) = \int f(gk.x)dk$ in 3.1 and the related $AN$ average in 3.5 $\int f(gu.x)du$. The $U$ action is unipotent, all eigvals are $1$, there cannot be any expansion whatsoever. The $A$ element is obviously $g$.The weak stable is essentially a unipotent subgroup action (extended by a compact and a diagonal). Obviously the only source of xpansion is the diagonal part, but if you actually follow the definitions, there is no expansion there as the action is

Comment: cont -  isometric. The coice of $P^{0}$ was an opposite parabolic, there's obviously where the expansion happen. $U$ is the horospherical subgroup related to $g$, the group $N$ is the complete nilpotent (notice that you have weights, $g$ is not a generic Cartan element). These all are standard subgroups in dynamics...

Comment: Can you please let me know what you mean by expansion of a Markov operator? Then $P^0$
 as you mentioned is opposite parabolic where the expansion happen. I am not sure what you are meaning by expansion? Another thing you mentioned that $P^0$ is opposite parabolic which is common in dynamics. Any standard reference or book for this ? I have gone through the book of Einsiedler and Ward where geodesic and horocycle flows (i.e unipotent) have neen mentioned but not parabolics or the group $N$.